# black screen no output error in displaying video/webcam feed in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV. I want to display video/webcam feed in OpenCV.I have written the following code

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,img  = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame",img)
```

[image]

Instead of getting webcam feed or video, I get a black screen with no output as shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `cv.waitKey(1)` or some other ms number as you wish. This will display a frame for 1 ms. Check the example [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html):

```
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```